# Show $P(1), P(2),...,P(99)$ true statements but $P(100)$ is false.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

> Provide a sequence of statements, $P(n),$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $P(1), P(2),...,P(99)$ are all true but $P(100)$ is a false statement.

My try:  Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $0\notin \mathbb{N}$. Suppose $P(n)$ is the statement that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $1\leq k < 100,$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}.$ Then all statements $P(1), P(2),...,P(99)$ are true and $P(100)$ is false.

My try seems really stupid and weak, how else can this be shown. The directions say to state this sequence very simply...is this good enough or is there a better way to answer?

Comment: I got $99$ problems but $P(100)$ is one.

Comment: @crash please explain, is this good enough?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well, "n != 100" seems to be sufficient but it just seems too...easy.

Comment: @user437158 It was an apparently [failed attempt at humour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwoM5fLITfk). My apologies. I'll delete the comment if you wish.

Comment: @crash it's ok, thanks :)

Comment: The proposed $P(n)$ in the question doesn't make much sense. The "for all $n$" quantifier means $n$ is not free, so the statement contains no variable corresponding to the free $n$ in $P(n)$; but it does contain a free variable $k$. I think maybe the example you were trying to make was that $P(n)$ is the statement that $1\leq n < 100$.

Comment: @DavidK thanks, should I say $x_n$ instead of just $n$, and indicate that $x_n \leq x_{n+1} < 100$

Comment: Hit him! Or @crash him and hit me :-/

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You edited your comment with :/ face. Why so my dear $\blacklozenge$?

Comment: @user437158 If you replace one of the $n$s with $x_n$, now you have at least three variables ($n$, $x_n$, and $k$), still with no connection between the parameter of $P$ and the contents of $P$. To make $P(n)$ meaningful and to make it have different truth values for some values of $n$, _do_ use $n$ inside the statement of $P$ but _do not quantify_ $n$ within the statement of $P$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P(i)$ be the statement that number $i$ is less than $100$.

Answer (score 2):

How about the statement $n \not= 100$?

Comment: One of these "Wait, is that allowed?  There must be more to it." things - but I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

I would use $$P(n) = \{n \neq 100\},$$ Or $$P(n) = \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n n < 5050 \right\}.$$